# Trying to automate channel permissions but it updates all the roles in the room with either read or write together

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been trying to make it so the Host role on my discord server can use either a !host or !stophosting command to unlock or lock their channel.  !host is correctly opening the channel back up, but !stophosting is locking everyone except admins out of the channel.  I want hosts to still have access to it.

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const client = new Discord.Client();
    client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    });

    client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.includes(`${prefix}stophosting`)) {
    let channel = message.channel;
    let roles = message.guild.roles; // collection
    const memberRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'member');
    const defaultRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'default');
    const hostRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Host');
    channel.overwritePermissions([
    {
    id: defaultRole.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    ], 'Lockdown')
    channel.overwritePermissions([
    {
    id: memberRole.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    ], 'Lockdown')
    channel.overwritePermissions([
    {
    id: hostRole.id,
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    ], 'Lockdown')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
    }
    });
    client.login(token);
```

Comment: Anyone that has a role that has `Administrator` permission can bypass those permissions, that's why they can view the channel.

Comment: I’m trying to not lock out the host role though is all.  I understand the admins staying.  That is not an issue.

Comment: Is the Host role above the Default and Member roles?

Comment: Yes.  The command is only updating the whole permissions list with the last one in the code.

Comment: So I ended up manually removing the default role from the people I chose, and just made the host command resync the permissions with the category.  Not at all how I want to keep it but it will work for now.